# Can't start Apache after attempt to upgrade to PHP 5.3.8

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, php, php53

After attempting to upgrade my PHP version on Windows 7, I cannot start Apache. I get this error message:

[image: The requested operation has failed!]

- I used the [Windows installer](http://windows.php.net/download/) to upgrade to PHP 5.3.8 from 5.2, afterwards I was unable to start Apache. I had stopped the server before the upgrade.
- I ensured all virus software was disabled during all upgrade and repair attempts, and rebooted between each. Default installation settings were used in all cases.
- I did not see anything in `error.log`
- I tried the "Repair" option in the PHP installer, as well as different installation settings.

I tried reinstalling Apache, but it did not seem to help and I got this error during the installation:

[image]

I see this in `httpd.conf`:

```
#BEGIN PHP INSTALLER EDITS - REMOVE ONLY ON UNINSTALL
###PHPIniDir "C:/Program Files/PHP/"
###LoadModule php5_module "C:/Program Files/PHP/php5apache2_2.dll"
#END PHP INSTALLER EDITS - REMOVE ONLY ON UNINSTALL

#BEGIN PHP INSTALLER EDITS - REMOVE ONLY ON UNINSTALL
##PHPIniDir "C:/Program Files/PHP/"
##LoadModule php5_module "C:/Program Files/PHP/php5apache2_2.dll"
#END PHP INSTALLER EDITS - REMOVE ONLY ON UNINSTALL

#BEGIN PHP INSTALLER EDITS - REMOVE ONLY ON UNINSTALL
#PHPIniDir "C:/Program Files/PHP/"
#LoadModule php5_module "C:/Program Files/PHP/php5apache2_2.dll"
#END PHP INSTALLER EDITS - REMOVE ONLY ON UNINSTALL

#BEGIN PHP INSTALLER EDITS - REMOVE ONLY ON UNINSTALL
PHPIniDir "C:/Program Files/PHP/"
LoadModule php5_module "C:/Program Files/PHP/php5apache2_2.dll"
#END PHP INSTALLER EDITS - REMOVE ONLY ON UNINSTALL
```

...but I have no idea what to do with it.

Nothing I've found on this site has been helpful although I have found similar questions. I'm guessing that more information would be needed from me, but I'm not sure what, but I'm happy to provide it.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Have you verified whether the file referenced in the error messages and the LoadModule directive actually ***EXISTS***? :-)

Comment: @voretaq7: No, it does not exist. I have no clue whether it should or should not, or what to do about it.

Comment: +1 for no other reason than having an awesome name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the error message says, that the file "cannot be found", please check the location of your "php5apache2_2.dll" - maybe the installer did something strange and the file is not there (anymore). Further, I'd suggest NOT to use the installer. There are zip-Files for download at [php.net](http://windows.php.net/download/). Download and unzip it in your directory "C:/Program Files/PHP/".

Edit: please also check the windows event log - what does it say?

If this does not help, try to download PHP 5.3.4 VC6 from [php-archive](http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/), which is compiled with the legacy visual studio 6 compiler -> "If you are using PHP with Apache 1 or Apache2 from apache.org you need to use the VC6 versions of PHP".

I hope, this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look ASAP. I'm currently scrambling to patch 40 sites after our server upgraded to php 5.3 and I failed to set a default timezone (new requirement I guess) or turn off error reporting!

Comment: @Wesley Murch: Maybe this helps not to patch all 40 sites? => http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone

Comment: Ahh yeah should have thought of that and emailed the server guy (he has control over the php.ini), I just finished patching (it was quick) but will send the request to him anyways, great advice. Moving on to your post's advice right now...

Comment: Although the VC9 releases were offered on the downloads page, I had to use the 5.3.4 VC6, just like you said. I unzipped it into `C:\Program Files\PHP` and this fixed everything, thank you so much! Not sure what I would have done without your help!

Comment: @WesleyMurch: I'd be glad to help!